# css issue so much space in the footer of the site

Tags: css

please visit link : http://hotwhelstoys.com/

in the footer ,you can see so much empty space is present.

I want to remove the footer space.

please help me what css i have to use to remove this footer space

Comment: The element ```<div id="bg_fade"></div>``` is at fault I have no idea what it does it why it is present. Looks like it could be part of some modal. And it didn't init right

Comment: please post your commment as answer...

Comment: I have done as asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<div id="bg_fade"></div>` is at fault I have no idea what it does it why it is present. Looks like it could be part of some modal. And it didn't init right